# Could not find txt file (issue with file path)

Tags: android, xamarin

I was having some issues trying to find a certificate for a `HttpWebRequest`, so I tried something much easier just to try to understand what I'm doing wrong.

So, the code I'm trying here is very simple:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\example.txt");
Console.WriteLine("Contents of example.txt = {0}", text);
```

And the exception I'm getting is:

> *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\example.txt"*

I noticed that there is a forward slash added just before "C:\"... what's the reason for it? I might be wrong, but I believe that could be preventing me from finding any files in the tests I've done so far.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You tagged the post with Xamarin. Are you using cross platform code? What platform are you running on? Your path seems like a Windows path but iOS uses forward  slashes for it's paths so if we were by chance running the code in iOS it could explain the beginning forward slash.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm using Xamarin but I'm building an Android app. As I was doing a quick test it didn't occur to me that probably I should be storing and looking for the file in some other way (avoiding Windows paths). That might be it. Not sure how, though, as I've never used certificates before.

Comment: an Android app runs in the context of an Android device/emulator - it can't "see" things that are on your desktop, it can only access files that are local to it